# How to calculate a completion rate in excel from a range of results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentage

Here is the information I have:

[image: Sprint rates]

I want to have a calculation in which I have a percentage of total sprints that have 100% been completed, so an overall sprint completion rate.

So for this information, the overall completion rate would be 0%, as none have been fully completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
COUNTIF(,1)/COUNT()
```

with suitable cell references.